# POST Request to Spotify Web Api using Laravel 5.2 Request

Tags: api, laravel, http-post, laravel-5, spotify

I've been looking into this for a while, but cant seem to find a solution, or atleast not none I understand.
The main question here is, Can I send a POST request with body and header to Spotify web API, using only Laravels 5.2 Request?

Maybe something like this.

```
        $parameters = array(
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'code' => $request->input('code'),
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/callback',
        );
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($client_id. ':' . '$client_secret'),
        );
return redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token')->withInput($headers, $parameters);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do it instead of using GuzzleHttp\Client e.g.?

Comment: I wanted to know if it was possible, if it is included on laravel why should I use something else, but yea if I can't I could use something else I did find some solutions using guzzle but I haven't tested, is that the only way? Some external libs?

Comment: @RodrigoCervantesSaucedo Guzzle is a full featured and well tested HTTP client used in many PHP frameworks and libraries including Laravel. So why not use it?